# What is the way to implement loop inside call method of Spark for n number of cases as this code runs on different executors?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to implement a loop inside call method of Spark for n number of cases:

```
int counter=0
while (counter <N)
{
 //do something

counter++;

}
```

This I have to do inside call method of Spark. However in the case of call method,  the counter will be at the driver while code inside will be on executers.  How to do this in case of spark?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to keep your "while" logic, you can use a Spark [Accumulator](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators):

```java
Accumulator<Integer> counter = sc.accumulator(0);

while (counter.value < N) {
     myRDD.foreach(x -> {
         counter.add(1); 
         // do something
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks. Actually, I should have explained the issue more clearly. The exact issue is that N is determined in the code inside a Map method (e,g    myRDD.map ).  If inside the map method I set it as a variable N and later try to use it in the above while loop, N is coming as 0.

Comment: @SauravR In that case, I suggest you edit your question with a code snippet that represents better your situation. Also, if you can show a reproducible example, with a simple RDD, would be a plus.

Comment: The issue is resolved after sending the accumulator counter using a broadcast variable and accessing it inside the while loop. Thanks